# How to login to webpage with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I have a web scraping program that needs to login in to a website to scrape certain data. Right now I am just trying to scrape the account information page,https://www.starcitygames.com/myaccount/, in order to get it working before I scrape the data I actually need.  And there are several Urls I need to scrape but only one needs a login.  But all the URLs I am scraping are on the same website.  Right now though it does not appear to be doing anything.  I try logging in but nothing happens, no message saying success, but also no message saying cannot login.  I even tried accessing the URL without the login code thinking I should get a message saying login required, but again nothing.  It accesses the page, but once it sees there is nothing to scrape it moves on.  Nothing about logging in.

SplashSpider.py

```
# Import from other python files and scrapy files and the needed csv file containing all URLs/proxies/ua
import csv
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem
#from scrapy.http import Request
##########################          SPALSHSPIDER.PY OVERVIEW      #####################################################
# process the csv file so the url + ip address + useragent pairs are the same as defined in the file
# returns a list of dictionaries, example:
# [ {'url': 'http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Rivals%20of%20Ixalan',
#    'ip': 'http://204.152.114.244:8050',
#    'ua': "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9320; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.11"},
#    ...
# ]
# plus python file also scrapes all URLs returning needed info and goes to all apges associated with URL by clicking next button

# Function to read csv file that contains URLs that are paried with proxies and user agents
def process_csv(csv_file):
    # Initialize data
    data = []
    # Initialize reader
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)

    # While inside csv file and not at end of csv file
    for fields in reader:

        # Set URL
        if fields[0] != "":
            url = fields[0]
        else:
            continue # skip the whole row if the url column is empty
        #Set proxy and pair with correct URL
        if fields[1] != "":
            ip = "http://" + fields[1] + ":8050" # adding http and port because this is the needed scheme
        # Set user agent and pair with correct URL
        if fields[2] != "":
            useragent = fields[2]
        # Put all three together
        data.append({"url": url, "ip": ip, "ua": useragent})
    # Return URL paried with ua and proxy
    return data

# Spider class
class MySpider(Spider):
# Name of Spider
    name = 'splash_spider'
    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):
        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)
            for i, req in enumerate(requests):
                x = len(requests) - i  # <- check here
                # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                        # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                        headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                        # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                        splash_url = req["ip"],
                        priority = x,
                        meta={'priority': x}
                        )

    # Scraping function that will scrape URLs for specified information
    def parse(self, response):

        # Initialize item to function GameItem located in items.py, will be called multiple times
        item = GameItem()
        # Initialize saved_name
        saved_name = ""
        # Extract card category from URL using html code from website that identifies the category.  Will be outputted before rest of data
        item["Category"] = response.css("span.titletext::text").get()
        # For loop to loop through HTML code until all necessary data has been scraped
        for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            # Initialize saved_name to the extracted card name
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").get() or saved_name
            # Now call item and set equal to saved_name and strip leading '\n' from output
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            # Check to see if output is null, in the case that there are two different conditions for one card
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                # If not null than store value in saved_name
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            # If null then set null value to previous card name since if there is a null value you should have the same card name twice
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            # Call item again in order to extract the condition, stock, and price using the corresponding html code from the website
            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["Stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").get()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").get()
            if item["Price"] == None:
                item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span[style*='color:red']::text").get()

            # Return values
            yield item
            # Finds next page button
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "- Next>>")]/@href').get()
        # If it exists and there is a next page enter if statement
        if next_page is not None:
            # Go to next page
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)

        return scriapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata={'username': 'example@gmail.com', 'password': 'password'},
                callback=self.after_login
                )

    def after_login(self, response):

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if "Error while logging in" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed!")
        else:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            self.logger.error("Login succeeded!")
            #scraping code will go here once I can login in succcessfully
```

Partial CSV file

```
URL,IP Address,User Agent
https://www.starcitygames.com/myaccount//login,199.89.192.78,"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.3 Safari/533.19.4",,
http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Vanguard%20Oversized,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new spider to do it.  It made things easier than trying to do it inside the same spider I scraped the other data from the website, the one that did not require a login.  The same website and all but this way was just easier. The below code logged me in so now I can scrape the data I need.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import NameItem

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "LoginSpider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/"]

    def parse(self, response):

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formcss='#existing_users form',
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'email123@example.com', 'ex_usr_pass': 'password123'},
        callback=self.after_login
        )
```